# Get unique values corresponding to the keys from an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

My array looks like this

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    "Param1": "20",
    "Param2": "8",
    "Param3": "11",
    "Param4": "4",
    "Param5": "18",
    "Param6": "20",
    "Param7": "8"
  },
  {
    "Param6": "21",
    "Param7": "8",
    "Param8": "11",
    "Param9": "4",
    "Param10": "18"
  },
  {
    "Param1": "20",
    "Param2": "8",
    "Param3": "10"
  }
]
```

I wanted to remove the duplicate key value pairs existing in the objects.
Expected result:

```
arr1 = [
  {
    "Param1": "20",
    "Param2": "8",
    "Param3": "11",
    "Param4": "4",
    "Param5": "18",
    "Param6": "20",
    "Param7": "8"
  },
  {
    "Param6": "21",
    "Param8": "11",
    "Param9": "4",
    "Param10": "18"
  },
  {
    "Param3": "10"
  }
]
```

The desired output is an array containing objects having unique key value pairs. How can I get such an array?

Comment: I would be better if you also share what you've tried so far

Comment: Your initial array and the result don't match. In the initial `arr1[0].Param6` is `21`, in the end result `20`. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDg5Vw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay, will write an answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm:

- Create a map `seen` in the format of `{param: {value: boolean}}` which will indicate whether the param with this value was already seen
- Create a `result` array that will store the unique params
- Traverse through the input array, get the keys of the current element, and traverse through them.
- Check if the param with this value was already seen, if yes, ignore it; otherwise add it to the `result` and mark it as seen
- Return the `result` array.

Implementation:

```
const removeDuplicates = (arr: Record<string, string>[]) => {
    return arr.reduce<{
        seen: Record<string, Record<string, boolean>>;
        result: Record<string, string>[];
    }>(
        (acc, item) => {
            acc.result.push(
                Object.fromEntries(
                    Object.entries(item).filter(([key, value]) => {
                        acc.seen[key] = acc.seen[key] ?? {};
                        if (acc.seen[key][value]) return false;
                        acc.seen[key][value] = true;

                        return true;
                    }),
                ),
            );
            return acc;
        },
        { seen: {}, result: [] },
    ).result;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQRgFwwEoFNQICYA80CAlmAOYA0MxZ5AfANoC6MAvDIwFAy8wDePPsIAKiOAFs0MAOQAmAAwzKQ4bzEJJc9DIAcy1Wo2SAzDuTIDavsYkAWHXavWYtgKzn9Kl6-ESAbDpylt4utgDsOl6GAL6hvII+toGywc7WEVHpRn665iGGon4AnI7ZRZpSCp7ZcYaJYX7S8krxOZXastFJfmayyK2xKswA3FxcoJCwCFgSIABuWAAiAK4ADgA2JMBwUFgQ7DAAFIgI6Ni4hLQU1NcMLACU7PQChjNQKwhg8EgAdDN4FbALAEBrWCBYLBgc44ED4IhQUg3TCw+F3agAIxAIA2WDgYHo9DGPhmEBWGygMMuCKRVBoiLoTFGsXoR0KfBOwGA1BIewkTzYLzBPngXP++3JUF+axWEAAFmyRS4APIYgBWOClADMECAJABRMAM-aKpUi1Ua4BSqHGiBHXmzB6-LUkClYBBHI6MADWWAAntR5nANissMwBUL2WaXHAxRCoT7-awOLHgL942BE37WAB+HMCGLE6Nmkha46p9OQzO+7OMIMhsNPd6fb5a4MQovFkUVjNZ5h14Oh5MwRGhsZRrt8ZtfEcIMcT6MxB5taPLhd8B6dkXT76prfCOo+fg0KvofhxGCkyXoFgwQ8b8VkiljQvjSYQHFYX4bEDkI4zOZFlWTZtl2E1TmQB4Hi4IA)